# How can I convert this one line of ActionScript to C#?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3

I would like to convert this one line of code to C# code within a void:

```
param1:Function=null
```

I am aware that in the void, it would be like `"thing here" param1`, but I dont know what `"thing here"` would exactly be. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SimonWhitehead like: "Delegate del" ?

Answer (score 0):

There is collection of `Func<...>` classes - [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is probably what you are looking for:

```
 void MyMethod(Func<int> param1 = null)
```

This defines method that have parameter `param1` with default value `null` (similar to AS), and a function that returns `int`. Unlike AS in C# you need to specify type of the function's arguments.

So if you AS usage was

```
MyMethod(function(intArg, stringArg) { return true; })
```

Than in C# it would require `param1` to be of type `Func<int, siring, bool>` and usage like

```
MyMethod( (intArg, stringArg) => { return true;} );
```